# How to convert nested array of objects into one array of objects using javaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array which contains affiliate arrays, I don't want to access children of the array by index, my aim is to merge this data and and get the following result: `[{id:'11223', price:92},{id:'92221', price:90}]`, What is the best way to achieve this? Thanks.

Sum of the final reulst:

```js
let finalResult = [{id:'11223', price:92},{id:'92221', price:90}]

let sum = finalResult.reduce((acc, curr)=> {
return acc+ curr.price
}, 0)
console.log(sum)
```

`

Nested array:

```js
let nestedArray = [
  [
   { 
    id:'11223',
    price:92
    }
  ],
  
  [
   {
    id:'92221',
    price:90
   }
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the `nestedArray` as:

```
nestedArray.flat()
```

```js
let nestedArray = [
  [
    {
      id: "11223",
      price: 92,
    },
  ],

  [
    {
      id: "92221",
      price: 90,
    },
  ],
];

const arr = nestedArray.flat();
console.log(arr);
```